# Can I upload a JAR file to the android market?

Tags: google-play

I have 2 parts of program. One of them is server which will run on mobile and second one is client which will run on computer. Can I upload these 2 files (apk and jar) into android market together?
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

Android market supports only .apk binary.